# Change input name attributes after getting html data from action through AJAX in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple ajax request which get from server a generated HTML, like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/GetData'
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    data: ...,
    success: function(data) {
        // here I want to change `name` attributes of inputs
        // before print on page
        // but it doesn't work, so, how to manage this ?
        $(data).find("input[name='test']").prop("name", "anotherValue");

        $("myDiv").prepend($(data));
    }
});
```

and my action is simple:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetData(){
    return PartialView("myview", new MyModel());
}
```

I want to change input `name` attributes before print them in html page. If I do in `success` function (see above) then no change is made.

Why ? To to achieve this ?

Comment: `$(data).find("input[name='test']").attr("name", "anotherValue");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like

```
$("input").each(function() {
    if($(this).prop("name") == "test") $(this).prop("name", "anotherValue");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Data cannot be edited unless you append them to the DOM
So, use `String.Replace` function

```
       var removed=data.replace("name='test'","anotherValue")
         .replace('name="test"',"anotherValue");

    $("myDiv").prepend(removed);
```

or do this

```
    $(data).prependTo("myDiv").find("input[name='test']").prop("name", "anotherValue");
```

Comment: plz give a look to the second section of my answer